# How to get a value from input array by pressing enter button in ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom-events

I tried some ajax, but when I press enter button it is giving me the first array result. But I want in which field I am inputting value only this input value should get.

html code

```
<tbody class="item-table">
<?php foreach($findInvst as $v){                                                                    
$result = $this->M_join->investmentListt('investment_manage', array('invest_pro_id'=> $v->pro_id));                                                                     
?>
<tr>    
<td width="1%"><input  type='radio' id="delChecked" name='delChecked[]'  value="<?php echo $v->pro_id;?>"></td>
<td width="26%"><input type='text' readonly="readonly" name='' id='' value="<?php echo $v->invest_title;?>"></td>
<td width="7%"><input  type='text' readonly="readonly" name='' id='' value="<?php echo $v->asx;?>"></td>                                                                        
<td width="11%"><input type='text' readonly="readonly" name='' id='' value="<?php  echo $result->aa ;?>"></td>
<td width="9%"><input  type='text' readonly="readonly" name='' id='' value="<?php  echo $result->dataAmnt ;?>"></td>
<td width="11%"><input type='text' readonly="readonly" name='' id='' value="<?php  echo $result->amount ;?>"></td> 
<td width="11%"><input type='text'  name='market_p_unit[]' id='market_p_unit' value="<?php  echo $result->MarketValue ;?>"></td> 
<td width="10%"><input type='text' readonly="readonly" name='' id='' value="<?php  echo $result->shareValue ;?>"></td> 
<td width="5%"><input  type='text'  readonly="readonly" name='' id='' value="<?php  echo $result->oneFee; ?>"></td> 
<td width="9%"><input type='text' readonly="readonly" name='' id='' value="<?php echo $result->totalBrokkery_fee;?>"></td>                                                                      
</tr>
<?php }?>                                                           
</tbody>
```

Ajax code

```
$(function () {
$('#market_p_unit').keypress(function (e) {
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
//alert(code);
    if (code == 13) {
    var market_p_unit = $('#market_p_unit').val();
    alert(market_p_unit);
    }
    });
});
```

I want value like in Image:

[image]

Comment: can you add some working example here like fiddle, your question is bit unclear.

Comment: can you take a screen shot of your form and explain it more clearly??

Comment: Your goal is not clear. Please take a detailed example.

Comment: @CodeReady i wanted array value from input by pressing enter button

Comment: @sony added screen shot please let me know if there any solution exist

Comment: @ArmanBagheri bro my goal is getting array value by pressing enter button

Comment: do you want get value of array id="delChecked" ? @Sumonto

Comment: Try with onBlur and get the edited value using "$(this).val()"

Comment: @ArmanBagheri no i want,   name="market_p_unit[]"

Comment: @sony please can you give me the full ajax code ?

Comment: do you want value of brackets "market_p_unit[]" ? @Sumonto

Comment: @ArmanBagheri yes

Comment: you can go through the following thread for better understanding using jquery ajax. URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668310/save-values-from-editable-table-using-php

Comment: @sony i have already seen such solution. In your given link there is no input filed only is tr td but i am doing with input field so it wont work for me

Comment: you can use textboxes in the above example which I provided

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in the key down event in JQuery. Please try the following code.

```js
    $(function () {
        $(".txt").keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.which === 13) {
                alert($(this).val());
            }           
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="txt" value="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="txt" value="2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="txt" value="3" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="txt" value="4" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```